# Multiple redis connection with laravel and phpredis

Tags: php, laravel, redis, phpredis

How can I use different Redis connection with Laravel and phpredis, however, I followed the laravel documentation [using-multiple-redis-connections](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/redis#using-multiple-redis-connections) but whenever I call this connection it always return the Redis default connection.

here's my Redis array in the database.php config file

```
'redis' => [

    'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'phpredis'),

    'options' => [
        'cluster' => env('REDIS_CLUSTER', 'redis'),
        'prefix'  => env('REDIS_PREFIX', Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_database_'),
    ],

    'default' => [
        'url'      => env('REDIS_URL'),
        'host'     => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port'     => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
        'database' => env('REDIS_DB', '0'),
    ],

    'cache' => [
        'url'      => env('REDIS_URL'),
        'host'     => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port'     => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
        'database' => env('REDIS_CACHE_DB', '1'),
    ],

    'redisCustomConnection' => [
        'url'      => env('REDIS_CUSTOM_URL'),
        'host'     => env('REDIS_CUSTOM_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_CUSTOM_PASSWORD', null),
        'port'     => env('REDIS_CUSTOM_HOST', '6379'),
        'database' => env('REDIS_CUSTOM_DB', '0'),
    ],

],
```

here's `.env` file

```
REDIS_CUSTOM_URL=mycustom value
REDIS_CUSTOM_HOST=mycustom value
REDIS_CUSTOM_PASSWORD=mycustom value
REDIS_CUSTOM_HOST=mycustom value
REDIS_CUSTOM_DB=mycustom value
```

But it did not work it always return the default connection when I use

```
Redis::connection('redisCustomConnection');
```

#output

```
Illuminate\Redis\Connections\PhpRedisConnection {#3315
    #connector: Closure() {#3316
    class: "Illuminate\Redis\Connectors\PhpRedisConnector"
    this: Illuminate\Redis\Connectors\PhpRedisConnector {#3317 …}
    use: {
      $config: array:4 [
        "host" => "127.0.0.1"
        "password" => null
        "port" => "6379"
        "database" => "0"
      ]
      $options: array:3 [
        "cluster" => "redis"
        "prefix" => "buraq_database_"
        "parameters" => []
      ]
    }
    file: "./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Redis/Connectors/PhpRedisConnector.php"
    line: "26 to 30"
  }
  #config: array:4 [
    "host" => "127.0.0.1"
    "password" => null
    "port" => "6379"
    "database" => "0"
  ]
  #client: Redis {#3314
    isConnected: true
    host: "127.0.0.1"
    port: 6379
    auth: null
    mode: ATOMIC
    dbNum: 0
    timeout: 0.0
    lastError: null
    persistentId: null
    options: {
      TCP_KEEPALIVE: 0
      READ_TIMEOUT: 0.0
      COMPRESSION: NONE
      SERIALIZER: NONE
      PREFIX: "buraq_database_"
      SCAN: NORETRY
    }
  }
  #name: "redisCustomConnection"
  #events: null
  #supportsPacking: null
  #supportsLzf: null
  #supportsZstd: null
}
```

Comment: I figured it out I had to run `php artisan optimize:clear` now all is good, for anyone who faces the same issue.

Comment: I saw your name connection is correct, maybe you mean is the return data always same or null?